# Facing issue while trying to decrypt password using PBE(PBEWITHSHA1ANDDESEDE)

Tags: encryption, jasypt

I have created a jar for encryption using PBE(PBEWITHSHA1ANDDESEDE) algorithm with Jasypt jar file.

Creating encrypt password using this jar file on unix environment but when I am trying to decrypt that password in my local environment (Windows PC) it is throwing error. But when I am encrypting password in my local then same encrypt password I am able to decrypt in my local PC.

I am using jasypt jar file using "PBEWITHSHA1ANDDESEDE" algorithm. Please let me know, is there any environment dependency there in encryption and decryption logic like those password encrypted in unix env can not be decrypted in Windows environment ?